# SelectListItem Text not being displayed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to complete a form for users to sign up to an asp.net MVC website, I am struggling to get the dropdown lists to display text properly. The Model has the following:

```
public SelectList CountiesList;
```

In the constructor, entities is my database context:

```
CountiesList = new SelectList(
                from c in entities.Counties
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.CountyID.ToString(),
                    Text = c.County //the county name, nvarchar/string
                });
```

And in my cshtml:

```
<div class="align-center">
    <label>County</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.County, Model.DropDowns.CountiesList)
</div>
```

This is generating the dropdown with the right number of items from the lookup table but the displayed Text is 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' rather than the name of the County.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your DropDownListFor points to x.County, while when filling the list, you return Value & Text as a property. Shouldn't you point to x.Text then ?

Comment: I delete my answer, I find it with some research but it looks like it is not correct. I upvote you good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountiesList;

CountiesList =  from c in entities.Counties
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.CountyID.ToString(),
                    Text = c.County //the county name, nvarchar/string
                };
```

because you shoudn't fill a `SelectList` with an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Use either `SelectList` **or** an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, **but not both.**

Comment: This still isn't showing the name properly in the dropdowns but thanks for the pointer, I wasn't aware I was mixing them when I shouldn't.

Comment: Are you sure the `Country` property contains the name and it is not an object?

Comment: Yeah, it is just a string in the View Model which I want to set with the text from the SelectListItem text

Comment: Would you change this line and tell the result Text = "my test string";

Comment: No, you're absolutely right - I hadn't followed your code properly, apologies. I tried again and this is the right answer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your problem goes deeper than that because it is not normal to want to have a SelectList as a model. And I think that there are chances that storing a `Dropdowns` list in your model indicates a conception error.

Your model should probably be your `Entity` (a list of Counties?) and then you could bind a dropdownlist for Counties, by passing a second argument to the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper a `SelectList` created exactly the same way you do it while initiating your CountiesList right now.

Comment: My View Model ("Candidate") has the same fields as the underlying DB model which I wan't to create and save, but I included a nested class for the foreign key items as SelectItemLists which are populated in the Model's constructor when it is called in the controller and passed to the View. I am sure sure this isn't typical but this is my first stab at MVC so I'm still feeling it out - your answer suggests there it a way to do this without including these in the View Model so I will investigate that now. Thanks for your help.